# Computation of arithmetic intersection number.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have the following question to ask : For an arithmetic surface $C$ over $Spec(O_{k})$, let us consider the triple product $X :=C\times C\times C$. Call the usual projections $\pi _{i}:X\rightarrow C_{i}\hspace {0.1cm},i=1,2,3$ and $\pi _{ij} :X\rightarrow C\times C$ respectively. Let $[(z,g_{z})]\in \widehat {CH}^1(C)$ be an Arakelov divisor and $[(W,g_{W})]\in \widehat {CH}^1(C\times C)$. Let
$$\alpha :=\pi ^*_{1}([(z,g_{z})])\cdot \pi ^*_{23}([(W,g_{W})])$$
$$\beta := \pi ^*_{2}([(z,g_{z})])\cdot \pi ^*_{13}([(W,g_{W})])\hspace {0.1cm}.$$
Is it possible to relate the intersection number of $\alpha \cdot \beta $ with that of $[(z,g_{z})]^2$ ?